# Why does PHP's garbage collector slow down performance, and how to manage memory without it?

Tags: php, memory-management, garbage-collection, unset

This relates to a PHP 5.3 Cli application that processes a lot of data in a complex way, taking hours to run. Someone discovered that turning off garbage collection made it run a great deal faster (maybe as much as 50%).

The only article I've come across that mentions this performance hit is http://derickrethans.nl/collecting-garbage-performance-considerations.html. I'm not sure I follow it entirely, but it seems to suggest that it only applies to code with a lot of circular references.

Could someone shed some light on this please?

Also, given that we have turned gc off, is there any way to manually reduce memory? Using unset() has been suggested. A quick test has shown that eighty or so bytes is freed by unset() regardless of the size of the object. This suggests it's just unsetting the reference, which is borne out by what I have read online. Am I right in thinking that these eighty bytes would be freed anyway, even without garbage collection, when the variable falls out of scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just disabled the circular-reference-GC. The regular one still works.

The common GC tests, whether or not there are `zval`s ("memory"), that are not referenced by any variables, or properties anymore, and will free this memory. A circular reference is, when two or more objects references each other directly, or indirectly

```
$a = new stdClass;
$b = new stdClass;
$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;
unset($a, $b);
```

Now both objects reference each other, but they are both not referenced from anywhere else, so they are unreachable. This is, what the circular-reference GC tries to detect, but to find them, it iterates over every known object and finds out, if there is a reference "from outside". Its a little bit more complicated, but simplified thats it ;) So in structures with many references, espcially circular ones, it is a huge task.

Worth to mention: With `unset()` you only remove the reference, but don't free the memory (directly). This is done by the GC later (and it makes a good job :))

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but the manual is very unclear. So, is the regular one impossible to disable? (Not that I want to, just interested)

Comment: @naomi Yes, you can't disable it. There is also no reason (the impact is very small) and because you can't free the memory from within PHP yourself (`unset()` doesn't do this) you will have a huge problem :D

Answer (score 2):

You can manually remove cycles from your code by using `unset`. You clean up cycles from classes by implementing a `__destruct` function. `unset` all private, protected or public variables that reference other Objects.

It gets really tedious if you're applying this to an existing program but it is doable.

---

```
class A {
    public $ref;
    public function __destruct() {
        unset($this->ref);
        echo "destruct";
    }
}
$a1 = new A();
$a2 = new A();
$a1->ref = $a2;
$a2->ref = $a1;
```

This does **not** work:

```
unset($a1, $a2);
echo "--";
// prints --destructdestruct (in 5.3)
```

This works:

```
$a1->__destruct();
unset($a1, $a2);
echo "--";
// prints destructdestructdestruct-- (in 5.3)
```

Comment: You get my `+1` for the second usage of `__destruct()` I find useful _ever_ :D (First one was "closing resources, DB-conncections, files, ...")

Comment: OK, so, unset() doesn't free memory, but it DOES remove circular references, so it IS a good idea to use it (where appropriate) when the circular reference collector is disabled. Have I got that right?

Comment: Yes, you can use `unset` to remove cycles. `unset` itself doesn't free memory, it cleans up references. And if a piece of data has no references, it's cleaned up. It's easy for the GC to count references, but hard to detect the cycles.

Comment: The `__destroy` is not ever going to be called unless your object is already being destroyed (that is, the memory is going to be released). Using CPU time to unset any references within the object is not going to increase performance. However, if your destructor can break cycles between other objects (instead of unsetting one or more references from the destructed object to another object) then it makes sense.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen this indeed seems to be the case. You must call `__destruct()` manually on the objects before calling `unset`. See example code in my updated answer.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I usually add a public method tearDown() because I think that __destruct() should *only* be called when the object is really destroyed. I'd prefer writing `private method __destruct()` to force this but at least some PHP versions have problems with that. The object will then be automatically destroyed by PHP reference counting mechanism after it goes out of scope or the variable is overwritten.

Comment: Sounds good, but I can't imagine GC really being an issue in situations other than some exotic ones, like OPs case. Maybe we don't know how to make proper GC patterns because we don't encounter it enough.

Comment: The issue is most often used by some kind of caching references between multiple objects what would want to use weak references but PHP does not support those. Fortunately, the GC engine in PHP 5.3 is good enough (barely) to mostly hide this problem.